# Why do some Sitecore icons lack their smaller version?

Tags: content-editor

Some of the icons bundled with Sitecore 8 - in my case, core/32x32/home_green.png - seem to be missing their 16x16 counterpart; this causes the Content Editor tree to lack an icon.

I just downloaded the official Sitecore release (Sitecore 8.0 rev. 141212) to make sure I didn't have an older version of the Core.zip file.

Is this a known issue? Are some icons supposed to be broken like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue.

It is caused by the fact that some icons are missing in the \sitecore\shell\Themes\Standard\Core.zip\16x16 folder.

As workaround, please consider using Core3 icon collection instead of Core.
If this way is inconvenient for you, please copy the lack files from the \16x16 folder of the \sitecore\shell\Themes\Standard\Core3.zip archive to the \16x16 folder of the \sitecore\shell\Themes\Standard\Core.zip archive.

Comment: Thank you, I have indeed found _some_ such icons under Core3. Which solves the problem for me, but not for those who are hell-bent into having a purple home icon :)

Not terribly high priority, I know...